# Prevent display turn off in a Mobile Browser

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a Mobile Based web page & I'm using web socket connection to handle a chat room. But I want the display turning on every time when user go to the web page by mobile browser.

I tried to simulate Button Click from,

```
function eventFire(el, etype){
    if (el.fireEvent) { 
          el.fireEvent('on' + etype); 
     } else {
        var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
        evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false); 
        el.dispatchEvent(evObj); 
     } 
}
```

But still mobile display turn off after particular time. Please can anyone help me with this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since most mobile OSs require user interaction to stop the screen from going to sleep this is impossible from a website. You'll need to make a native app.

Comment: What about a small video loop?

Comment: @user3270784 no

Answer (score 20):

There is a Working Draft for a new [Wake Lock API](http://w3c.github.io/wake-lock/), which doesn't seem to be implemented anywhere.

For now, you can take a look at [NoSleep.js](https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js):

> Prevent display sleep and enable wake lock in all Android and iOS web browsers.

It requires user interaction though, meaning you have to attach it to a user input event handler (eg mouse/touch).

Comment: Been trying to use NoSleep.js on iOS Chrome 10.3, and doesnt work :(

Comment: it works well in current chrome and Xiaomi default browser. What it does is playing tiny, invisible, silent .mp4 in the background, which prevents most mobile browsers from turning off the screen. But I found out that not all browsers respect that, so it's not complex solution (unfortunately). I was looking for a solution that would prevent mobile browsers from going off while users listen to an .mp3 file in my web app and as of today I have not found it. The only solution is building Android/iOS app.

Comment: Sometimes NoSleep.js returns "ScreenWakeLock Access is disabled by feature policy" on smarthphones android

Comment: The Wake Lock API seems to have moved forward substantially in Chromium at least: https://web.dev/wake-lock/